# Aligning Checkboxes In a Row

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project for school that asks users which VR Device they like the most, and i'm trying to center the buttons so they align, but I don't know how to do it, I've been going through alot of things on stackoverflow, google,youtube but nothing has worked to make the checkboxes be in a row down
here's what the HTML looks like "https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyuk6.png"
here's what the CSS looks like "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeWbn.png"

Comment: You are required to place a minimal example showing the problem here, not a third-party site which can disappear tomorrow helping no one. And not a screenshot!

Comment: I'm sorry, I would do that but i'm not able to since i don't have 10 reputation yet, I will as soon as I get 10 rep then i'll edit it and make it a picture

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for (You can use own CSS):

```
Pick One Below
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" class="choose" value="male">Oculus Rift<br>
  <input type="radio" class="choose" value="female">HTC Vibe<br>
  <input type="radio" class="choose" value="other">Gear VR
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pratikhegde/h8dxo9ok/